# Python Qrcode problem with input in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, qr-code

i am trying to create an program that asks you an link and than it gives you an qrcode for that link.
but i cant use the input i ask for
so it just creates an qrcode with nothing.

I need help to ask an input to the user and then use that input converted it to an qrcode
i already fixed my open button i chagned the open. to show.

```python
import qrcode 
import tkinter
from PIL import Image



main = tkinter.Tk("Link converter to QrCode ")
main.title("Link converter to Qr Code")
main.geometry("685x85")


link = tkinter.Label(
    main, 
    width="30",
    text=('Link:'))
link.grid(row=0)


e1 = tkinter.Entry(
    main, 
    bd="5", 
    width="75",
    text=(""))
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

qrcode.make(e1.get())
img = qrcode.make(e1.get())

button_create = tkinter.Button( 
    main, 
    text="Click to create the Qrcode.",  
    command = lambda:qrcode.make(e1.get()) and img.save("")  )
button_create.grid(row=2, column=1)




button_open = tkinter.Button ( 
    main,  
    text="Click here to open the Qrcode", 
    command = lambda: img.show(""), 
    width="25")
button_open.grid(row=2, column=0)


exit_button = tkinter.Button(
    main,
    width=("15"),
    text='Exit',
    command= lambda: main.quit())
exit_button.grid(row=4, column=0)



main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write this line:

```py
img = qrcode.make(e1.get())
```

it creates an empty qr and when you call img, it returns this empty qr.
you must do the img inside a function and call it with the buttons. Here is the solution:

```
import qrcode 
import tkinter
from PIL import Image



main = tkinter.Tk("Link converter to QrCode ")
main.title("Link converter to Qr Code")
main.geometry("685x85")


link = tkinter.Label(
    main, 
    width="30",
    text=('Link:'))
link.grid(row=0)


e1 = tkinter.Entry(
    main, 
    bd="5", 
    width="75",
    text=(""))
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def makeqr():
    img = qrcode.make(e1.get())
    return img

button_create = tkinter.Button( 
    main, 
    text="Click to create the Qrcode.",  
    command = lambda:makeqr().save("")  )
button_create.grid(row=2, column=1)




button_open = tkinter.Button ( 
    main,  
    text="Click here to open the Qrcode", 
    command = lambda: makeqr().show(""), 
    width="25")
button_open.grid(row=2, column=0)


exit_button = tkinter.Button(
    main,
    width=("15"),
    text='Exit',
    command= lambda: main.quit())
exit_button.grid(row=4, column=0)



main.mainloop()
```